# How do i find out the file path of the files in specific branch in Git Bash?

Tags: git, file, path

So, i was writing a simple program that will update the value in a text file that is in the same branch with the program. Although i specified the file path of that text file but i am still getting the FileNotFoundError and i have attached the code and the error shown below.

```
with f:
        for line in f:
                print (line)
```

Error shown: **FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/c/Users/yee/GitHub try/one.txt'**

Comment: Can you add more codes? It looks the error is coming from other part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by replacing the file path from `/c/Users/yee/GitHub try/one.txt` to `../GitHub try/one.txt`

Answer (score 0):

you can try `git log --name-only`

Comment: I tried using the command but it is for showing the committed commits but not the file's path.